# Yammer REST APIs

Tags: python, api, restful-authentication, yammer

Using browser I can access https://www.yammer.com/mycompany.com page with my company email ID and password and read posts.

I want to read the posts programmatically. I have been going through the information available at https://developer.yammer.com/docs, not getting much clue.

Can someone suggest on how to connect(authenticate) and read the posts using python

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at python's "requests" library:

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/

You can also use Postman if you want to use a user interface (can help you better understand REST API):

https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html

Comment: Looking for Yammer REST APIs to access and read Yammer posts programmatically. not getting much clue from https://developer.yammer.com/docs/api-requests

I am able to ping www.yammer.com and tried this option, no luck
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.yammer.com', auth=('name@mycompany.com', 'password'))
- - -
Max retries exceeded with url: / 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
>>>

Comment: Try using `yammer.com/api/v1/` instead of `yammer.com` in requests.get(...). Maybe even use the full path provided at yammer.com `yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json`.

Comment: Unfortunately both are not helping. Any clue. How to generate bearer token